# access class by ip

Tags: c++, sockets, ip

I'm currently working on a UDP server.
I want to redirect all incoming packets to the connected clients by using the ip address and port.
My current way of doing it looks like this:

```
class Connection;
typedef std::map<unsigned short, Connection*> PortMap;
typedef std::map<unsigned int, PortMap> AddressMap;
```

So I'm basically using two maps. The second one contains a map of all the ports using an ipv4 address(unsigned int) as a key. The PortMap uses the port as the key and it contains a pointer to the Connection class(the clients).

I speed tested it by accessing 64 clients using randomly generated ips and ports and it took ~ (**EDIT** : 0.4 milliseconds) to access 64 different clients 64 times.
I don't know really if it's slow or not. Of course it depends on the system I'm running the test on.

Here's how I'm accessing the client using the address:

```
Client * GetClient(Address address)
{
    AddressMap::iterator ipIt;
    PortMap::iterator portIt;
    unsigned int ip = address.GetAddress();
    unsigned short port = address.GetPort();

    /// Does the ip exist?
    if((ipIt = clientAddresses.find(ip)) == clientAddresses.end())
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    /// Does the port exist?
    if(clientAddresses[ip].find(port) == clientAddresses[ip].end())
    {   
        return NULL;
    }

    return clientAddresses[ip][port];
}
```

Does anyone know another faster way of doing it?

Comment: consider that your average home dsl/cable link has a latency of ~40-50ms for local-ish connections. you did 64 connections in 400ms. that's pretty good.

Comment: How about `pair<unsigned int, unsigned short>` for map key?

Comment: Thank you, it's actually as fast as Olympian's solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it'll be better to combine IP and Port..

Port < 65535. You can get key: IP * 65535 + Port, it'll be unique for all ports and IPs.

About speed: for example we have N Ip's, each IP has M ports.

Searching into map has efficient N log(N), so your search take N*M*log(N)*log(M).
If you combine IP and port into one key, efficient will be N*M*log(N*M).
log(N*M) = log(N)+log(M) < log(N)*log(M), for big N, M..

So, I think it'll be better.

Comment: But then I have to store the index as an 64 bit integer since else the value will wrap-around, right?

Comment: you could do that, or you could write your own compare operator

Comment: Yes, you'll need 64 bit keys.. It'll take extra memory, but provide high speed.

Comment: Wow, I'm down at 0.07ms using an unsigned long long as the key :D
Thanks both of you.

Answer (score 0):

64 accesses into a map taking 400ms sounds horrifically slow... check your measurements.  Your map should probably be based on a combination of IP and port (not separate), since a NAT can combine clients under a specific IP.

Comment: Wow, I mean 0.4 ms! Also it's 64*64 access+ getting the pointer to the client using the address and setting some garbage data to the client(which is supposed to be the packet)

Comment: even still... if that doesn't account for network traffic, 4K accesses shouldn't take long...

Comment: That's why I'm asking you for another solution. How would you combine them?

Comment: I see you've edited the question now and added `GetClient(Address address)`... what you have doesn't look bad and will handle NAT fine.  You might access the iterators directly though so you don't inadvertently run multiple searches (depends on compiler optimizations)... i.e. instead of `clientAddresses[ip].find(port)` you could do `portIt = ipIt->second.find(port)` and `return portIt->second;`.  It looks like you've edited the question from 0.4s to 0.4ms... that sounds much better...

Comment: Yes, sorry for the typos. Your "fix" decreased the time to 0.2ms instead of 0.4ms, thanks! Do you think this is pretty much the fastest way of doing it?

Comment: What you have is good.  A combined IP/Port map might be a hair faster, but it would depend on client distribution, and it's a more complex.  You could also consider a hash function, but again, would depend on client distribution.  I'd leave it with what you have.